# RedBean не могу совместить WHERE и Order

Tags: php, redbeanphp

не так давно начал работать с либой RedBeanPhp, возникла проблема в написании строки кода. Выдаёт ошибку, когда я в 1 запросе хочу достать все строки с одной категории по запросу, и пытаюсь их отсортировать в порядке убывания по id.

Вот пример который я пытался написать сам, но он не работает:

```
$result = R::findAll('content', 'WHERE category = ?', array($data), 'ORDER BY id DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил

```
$result = R::findAll('content', 'WHERE category = :data ORDER BY id DESC', array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = R::findAll('content', 'category= ? ORDER BY id DESC', [$data]);

$result = R::findAll('content', 'category= ? AND rate >= ? AND name LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC', [$data, 50, '%Телефон%']);

$result = R::findLike('content', ['category' => [$data1,$data2,$data3], 'rate' => '100' ]);
```

может поможет :)

Comment: https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding тут подробно описано все :)